# LNK1181 error when compiling V8 engine on Win10

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, v8

I'm following this guide on [building V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN) but I am hitting some issues on the compilation step. I am running Windows 10 x64. I am trying to compile with options to embed the engine also.

Running the following command:

`ninja -C out.gn/x64.release`

Gives me this error:

```
ninja: Entering directory `out.gn/x64.release'
[1/471] LINK mksnapshot.exe mksnapshot.exe.pdb
FAILED: mksnapshot.exe mksnapshot.exe.pdb
C:/Workspace/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_6_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/toolchain/win/tool_wrapper.py link-wrapper environment.x64 False link.exe /nologo /OUT:./mksnapshot.exe /PDB:./mksnapshot.exe.pdb @./mksnapshot.exe.rsp
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'comdlg32.lib'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

---

Now I believe I have narrowed down the error to looking for the `.lib` files in the wrong directory. I have (had) multiple versions installed, so there were multiple folders in my Windows Kit install.

`Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0`
`Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.15xxx.0`

If I dragged and dropped the `comdlg32.lib` file from `10.0.16299.0` into the `10.0.15xxx.0` directory then the error changed to a `LNK1181` error with a different input file. I did this a few times but I was unsure if this was going to cause issues with different versions and there was probably going to be a lot.

I uninstalled the `10.0.15xxx.0` version which left behind the folder I mentioned, so I removed that and after doing so I have started getting the `LNK1181` error with a different input file (`advapi32.lib` I assume the very first file it can't find). This is how I came to the conclusion about the path being incorrect.

---

So I have tried a few things to change the path (I hoped just uninstalling the old version would fix it) such as:

- Uninstalling the old version.
- Going through registry entries to see if I can find an install path or something using that path, which I didn't. I did notice that there was still installation and data in the registry for the `10.0.15xxx.0` install, I might try deleting that from the registry directly as a last resort?
- I have tried to explicitly set the path by setting `<TargetUniversalCRTVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetUniversalCRTVersion>` in this file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\uCRT.props`
- I have never used Ninja before so I tried looking for a way to set some kind of `lib-path` in the command but couldn't really find anything.
- I looked through the python scripts being executed to try and locate something to do with the libs path but couldn't see anything.

---

I would be grateful for any help and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Building such big projects on windows is always been a big mess. Try linux you will breeze through the build process.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to embed the engine into a Windows application I'm working on. I might do that though so I can at least play around with it until I get it to compile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile v8 using Visual Studio as explained here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#using-the-visual-studio-ide

By running the following commands:

```
$ gn gen --ide=vs out.gn/x64.release
$ cd out.gn/x64.release
$ msbuild all.sln
```

You can see a full example here: https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/issues/272#issuecomment-262848754

Apparently this method is not officially supported anymore, but I had the same problem as you have and this solved the issue for me.

Note that after this I had another issue, the unit tests failed to be compiled due to a linking error, but I had the necessary libraries to use v8. So there may be deeper problem that is causing all of this that I'm missing.

Edit:

Also, you could try to set the following parameters with `gn args`:

```
visual_studio_path = "..."
visual_studio_version = "2017"
wdk_path = "..."
windows_sdk_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10"
```

To set those parameters, do:

```
gn args out.gn/x64.release
```

This will open a text editor where you can write the extra parameters you are interested in.

To see the full list of parameters you can specify:

```
gn args --list out.gn/x64.release
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following this guide https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4 and also ran into the error

```
LINK1181: cannot open input file 'advapi32.lib'
```

I'm pretty sure it was because I had the wrong versions of the Windows 10 SDK. Similar to you I had versions:

```
Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.10240.0
Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0
```

But according to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Setting-up-Windows (Which I think is relevant) you need version `10.0.15063.0`

After installing version `10.0.15063.0` (with the visual studio installer) to

```
Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.15063.0
```

I was able to continue with the build.